# Check if a word is in a list OCAML using fold

Tags: list, ocaml

Suppose I want to extract a 4-letter word out of 6-letter word, say "hank" out of "thanks". Suppose there is also a list of 4-letter words that makes sense and I want to check that whether the 4-letter word I just extracted makes sense (i.e if it shows up in the list of 4-letter words) and then I want to return a list of all 6-letter words from which extracted meaningful 4-letter words come.
My thought is:

```
let is_4_init lst = 
    let acc = ([]) in
            let f (group) x =
                    let y = String.sub x 1 4 in
                    if List.mem y my_4words_list then ([x]) in
            let (final_group) = List.fold_left f acc lst in final_group
```

> Error: This variant expression is expected to have type unit
>          The constructor :: does not belong to type unit

why is this the case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `if ... then` without an `else`, then the type of the result must be `unit`. That's because the type needs to be the same for both cases. `unit` is the type of the value `()`, and is used when the result of an expression isn't particularly interesting.

Your function f should be returning an accumulated result, so it does return an interesting result. Returning `unit` is not what you want. You need to figure out what `f` should return when the test is false.

As a side comment, it's somewhat notable that you're not using the parameter named `group` anywhere.

Comment: I am not sure how to handle the "else" case because if that 4-letter-word does not make sense, I want to move on to the next word and ignore the last one. I understand my variable group is not used any where. Can I use "_" for that? Thank you!

Comment: No, you need to use `group`. If you figure out how to use `group` it will answer both questions.

Comment: I think I got it now. If I have another question, should I create a new topic?

Comment: My next step is to make a list of string pairs, which contain all the pairs of (4-letter, 6-letter) as described above.
What is my strategy?